# Prevent triggering multiple triggers at same time on table update

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, triggers

In the SQL server, I have a table X and a table Y.
The primary key of both is same say Z.
I created a trigger that if anything is created/deleted/updated in X then

1. If the entry doesn't exist in Y for Z then create a new entry.
2. If an entry exists in Y for Z then update that row.

I ran a query like this:

```
Delete FROM Table2 where TId = 1;
```

This query deleted 10 rows and 10 triggers ran simultaneously. As all ran parallel every trigger executed the else block because there was no entry in Y initially for Z and as all are running they won't find the row in Y. So because of this 10 rows gets created in the Y table.

I want that I should get only 1 entry created and the other triggers should update that entry.

As example I have tables:

Table1(TId PRIMARY KEY, C12, C13);

Table2(C21 PRIMARY KEY, TId FOREIGN KEY(Table1, C11), C23);

Table3(TId PRIMARY KEY, C32, C33);

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[trg1] ON  [dbo].[TABLE2] AFTER DELETE
        AS
        BEGIN
        SET NOCOUNT ON
            IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Deleted D )
                    BEGIN
                        IF EXISTS (Select * from [dbo].[Table3] where TId in (Select TId from Deleted D) )
                            BEGIN
                                Update [dbo].[Table3] SET C32 = 1 where TId in (Select TId from Deleted D);
                        END
                        ElSE
                            BEGIN
                            INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table3]
                                (
                                    TId,
                                    C32,
                                    C33
                                )
                            SELECT  TId, 
                                    3,
                                    GETUTCDATE()
                            FROM Deleted D WHERE TId is not null
                            SET NOCOUNT OFF
                        END

            END
        SET NOCOUNT OFF
    END
            
PRINT '';
PRINT 'End of script';
PRINT ' --- // ---';
```

Comment: You need to provide a [MRE] with sample data, expected results, and your trigger code.

Comment: You've misdiagnosed your situation. In SQL Server, triggers execute once per *set* of rows affected, so no, you do not have 10 triggers running simultaneously. More likely is that your trigger has been incorrectly written to *assume* it's only dealing with one row at a time.

Comment: @DaleK I have updated the question with an example.

Answer (score 2):

Your entire trigger's code should be something like this:

```
MERGE INTO Table3 t
USING (SELECT TId,CASE WHEN COUNT(*) > 1 THEN 1 ELSE 3 END as C32
       FROM deleted
       GROUP BY TId) u
ON t.TId = u.TId
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET C32 = 1
WHEN NOT MATCHED AND u.TId is not null THEN
    INSERT (TId,C32,C33) VALUES (u.TId, u.C32, GETUTCDATE());
```

Which will insert a new row but decide whether to set `C32` to `1` or `3`, depending on how many rows in `DELETED` are for the same `TId`, and just update `C32` to `1` if a row already existed.

This is all about thinking *in sets*. You weren't accounting for the fact that `deleted` could contain multiple rows, some or all of which may have the same `TId` value. You don't write `IF`/`ELSE` blocks that can only make a single decision for all rows in `deleted`<sup>1</sup>.

---

<sup>1</sup>E.g. if deleted had contained 4 rows total, 2 for `TId` 6 and 2 for `TId` 8, and `Table3` had contained a row for `TId` 6 but no row for `TId` 8, your trigger would have found some matching rows in `Table3` and just performed the `UPDATE`.

Comment: What If I run Delete FROM Table2 where TId = 1; and 10 rows are deleted from Table2 with same TId and there is no row in Table3 for Tid = 1. Would it create one row only and update it for other triggers. If so, would there be any kind of lock to the tables if I run this?

Comment: @akshit - you keep thinking that multiple triggers are running. They aren't. This trigger code would run *once*, and its `deleted` table contains all 10 rows. As you can hopefully see, the subselect in the `USING` would (via the `GROUP BY`) reduce all of those rows down to one row (per `TId`) to try to match against rows in `Table3`.

Comment: Can you please help me to understand that when I ran with the previous trigger and same scenario, why it has created 10 rows at that time? I am sorry if this is a silly question. I have started working on this just recently.

Comment: @akshit - because there are 10 rows in `inserted`. None of them match a row in `Table3`. You then did an `INSERT ... SELECT` from `inserted`. That's why you got 10 rows.